# why python is printing 2 "the"s, is an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code has to take the file and put all the words in a list, and then check if they are not repeated, if necessary delete them until it is only 1. However, only  the "the" puts it several times
enter code here:

```
    plbrs_totales = list()
    fnombre = input("Ingrese nombre de archivo:\n")
    try:
      llave = open(fnombre)
    except:
      print("Error")
      quit()
    for lineas in llave:
      lineas_ind= lineas.rstrip()
      plbrs = lineas_ind.split()
      plbrs_totales = plbrs_totales + plbrs
    for rep in plbrs_totales:
      repwords = plbrs_totales.count(rep)
      if repwords > 1:
       plbrs_totales.remove(rep)
    plbrs_totales.sort()
    print(plbrs_totales)
```

y este es el archivo.txt:

```
But soft what light through yonder window breaks\n
It is the east and Juliet is the sun\n
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon\n
Who is already sick and pale with grief\n
```

and this is the output, why are 2 "the"?

> ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks',
> 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon',
> 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'the', 'through', 'what',
> 'window', 'with', 'yonder']

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are modifying the list you are iterating over. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) should answer the why.

As to how you could do it, you would want to replace the second `for` loop with this.

```py
plbrs_totales = list(set(plbrs_totales))
plbrs_totales.sort()
print(plbrs_totales)
```

The `set` method will return a **set** with each item in `plbrs_totales` occuring once while the `list` method converts the **set** back to a **list**.

Comment: i understand now, but why the only element that prints bad is "the", if you see "and" its works well. is this becouse i modify the list?

Comment: Yes. There are only 3 **the** in your text, so I'm guessing that the `for` loop only ever got to see one hence only one was removed.